# Show that $f \overset{T}{\rightarrow} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(t) dt$ is Bounded, and is NOT Compact in $L^2(0, \infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Can someone help me with this question?

Let $f \in X = L^2(0, \infty)$, and define
\begin{equation}
(Tf)(x) = \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(t) dt \ .
\end{equation}
Show that $T$ is Bounded, and is NOT Compact.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** For boundedness, I tried:
\begin{eqnarray}
\| f \| \leq 1 \Rightarrow \| Tf \|^2 &=& \int_0^{\infty} \lvert (Tf)(x) \rvert ^2 \ dx \\
&=& \int_0^{\infty} \lvert \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x f(t) \ dt \rvert ^2 \ dx \\
&\leq& \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} \int_0^x \lvert f(t) \rvert ^2 \ dt \ dx \\
&\leq& \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} \| f \| ^2 \ dx \\
&=& \| f \| ^2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} \ dx \\
\end{eqnarray}
But the problem is that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} \ dx$ is NOT finite.

To prove that $T$ is not compact, I think we should give a sequence of functions, $\{ f_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, such that for every $n$, we have $\| f_n \| \leq 1$ and $\{ Tf_n \}$ has no Cauchy subsequence. But I can't find such sequence of functions.

Comment: Hi @HosseinMoradiDavijani ! Welcome to math.stackexchange.com, I see you are new here, in order to get more help, please share with us what are your thoughts on this problem and where are you finding difficulties.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Leo Sera. I added what you want.

Comment: For the second part, such a sequence would violate the boundedness of $T$. What you may want to look up is a bounded sequence whose image under $T$ has no Cauchy subsequence.

Comment: Thanks @sos440 , I correct it.

Comment: You should look into using Minkowski's integral inequality.  I have a solution to a more general problem here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175333/integral-inequality-does-this-look-correct.  Your problem is with p = 2 and alpha = 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought I would just offer an alternate solution using [Minkowski's integral inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski.27s_integral_inequality) applied to:

$$ \| Tf \|_2 = \left\{ \int_0^{\infty} \left( \int_0^x x^{-1} f(t)\,dt \right)^{2}\,dx \right\}^{1/2} $$

But first we do a variable substitution $t \rightarrow xt$ so the inner integral is integrating over a fixed space:

$$ \| Tf \|_2 = \left\{ \int_0^{\infty} \left( \int_0^1 f(xt)\,dt \right)^{2}\,dx \right\}^{1/2} $$

Minkowski's inequality then yields:

$$ \| Tf \|_2 \leq \int_0^1 \left \{ \int_0^{\infty} f^2(xt)\, dx \right\}^{1/2}\, dt $$

Now undo our variable substitution, this time sending $x \rightarrow x/t$, and get:

$$ \| Tf \|_2 \leq \int_0^1 \left \{ \int_0^{\infty} t^{-1} f^2(x)\, dx \right\}^{1/2}\, dt = \left( \int_0^1 t^{-1/2}\,dt \right)\left ( \int_0^{\infty} f^2(x)\,dx\right )^{1/2}$$

And, of course, $\int_0^1 t^{-1/2}\,dt$ is finite.

To answer your second question.  Let

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
& 0 & x \leq 0 \\
& 1 & 0 < x < 1/2 \\
& -1 & 1/2 \leq x \leq 1 \\
& 0 & 1 \leq x
\end{cases} $$

So $\|f\|_2 = 1$.  Now let $f_n(x) = n^{-1/2}f\left(\frac{x - n}{n}\right)$.  So,

$$\|f_n\|_2 = n^{-1/2} \left( \int_n^{2n} dt \right)^{1/2} = 1.$$

The important property here is that $\int_0^1 f(t) dt = 0$.  This is going to ensure that $Tf_n$ have disjoint support.  Why? Recall:

$$ Tf_n(x) = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x n^{-1/2} f\left(\frac{t-n}{n}\right)\,dt $$

Since $f(x)$ is $0$ for $x < 0$ we have that $Tf_n$ is 0 for $x < n$.  And since $\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt =0 $, we have:

$$ Tf_n(2n) = \frac{1}{2n} \int_n^{2n} f\left(\frac{t - n}{n}\right)\,dt = \frac{1}{2n} \int_0^n f\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\,dt = 0$$

And you can see that $Tf_n(x) = 0$ for $x > 2n$.  So if we take $f_{2^k}$ as $k = 1, 2, 3, \dots$ we can see that $Tf_{2^k}$ have disjoint supports.  So to prove that these have no convergent subsequence you just need to show that $\|Tf_k\|_2$ is bounded below for any integer $k$. We will estimate $\| Tf_k \|_2^2$ but only focus on those x where $f_k$ is positive.

$$\| Tf_k \|_2^2 = \int_k^{2k} \frac{1}{x^2} \left\{ \int_0^x f_k(t)\,dt \right\}^2\,dt \geq \int_k^{3k/2} \frac{1}{4k^2} \left\{\int_k^x f_k(t)\,dt \right\}^2\,dx $$

We have:

$$ \int_0^x f_k(t)\,dt = k^{-1/2}(x - k) $$

for $k \leq x \leq 3k/2$.  So we get:

$$\| Tf_k \|_2^2 \geq \frac{1}{4k^2} \frac{1}{k} \int_k^{3k/2} (x - k)^2\, dx$$

And this can be shown to be bounded below be something like $1/100$.  Sorry, but nothing else comes to mind for proving this.

Comment: Thank you @breeden . Do you have any idea about proving non-compactness?

Comment: @HosseinMoradi - I sketched out something I came up with.  There could be a mistake, and it's a little messy, and I'm sure there is an easier example though.

Comment: Very nice solution @breeden . I think being bounded is not necessary. I just used this fact that we have disjoint supports. Please check that I am correct or not. Let $\{ f_{2^{n_i}} \}$ be a Cauchy sub-sequence. Then there exists $M$ so that $n_i, n_j > M \Rightarrow \| f_{2^{n_i}} - f_{2^{n_j}} \| < 1$. But we have: $\int_0^{\infty} \lvert f_{2^{n_i}} - f_{2^{n_j}} \rvert^2 = \int_{2^{n_i}}^{2^{n_i+1}} \lvert f_{2^{n_i}} \rvert^2 + \int_{2^{n_j}}^{2^{n_j+1}} \lvert f_{2^{n_j}} \rvert^2 > 1$.

Comment: @HosseinMoradi, I think you meant to write $Tf_{2^{n_j}}$ there instead of just $f_{2^{n_j}}$.  But yeah, the point of the disjoint supports is so it's easy to calculate $\|Tf_k - Tf_m\|^2 = \|Tf_k\| + \|Tf_m\|$.  And provided that $\|Tf_k\|$ is bounded below, then you get that $\|Tf_k - Tf_m\|$ can never go to zero.  But if $\|Tf_k\|$ did go to zero, then you can get that $\|Tf_k - Tf_m\|$ goes to zero to.  In this case, your sequence converges to the 0 function.

Comment: You are right I made mistake, Thanks. Sorry, again I can't understand why a below bound is necessary for $\| Tf_k \|$ to show that $\| Tf_k - Tf_m \|$ can not go to zero. Can you explain how you do that please?

Comment: Geometrically you think of it this way :you have a sequence of vectors that are perpendicular to each other than is no way they can converge (unless they are converging to zero).  But to be precise it goes like this: since $\|Tf_k\| \geq 1/100$ you get that for any $m, n$ you have $\|Tf_n - Tf_m\|^2 = \|Tf_n\|^2+\|Tf_m\|^2\geq 2/200$.  In particular this can't go to zero. Does this make sense?

Comment: Absolutely YES... Thank you @breeden :)

Answer (score 7):

For the boundedness, observe that

\begin{align*}
\| Tf \|_2^2
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} |Tf(x)|^2 \, dx \\
&\leq \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} \int_{0}^{x} \int_{0}^{x} |f(u)||f(v)| \, dudvdx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} |f(u)||f(v)| \left( \int_{u \vee v}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2} \right) \, dudv \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{|f(u)||f(v)|}{u \vee v} \, dudv \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{|f(r\cos\theta)||f(r\sin\theta)|}{\cos\theta \vee \sin\theta} \, drd\theta \\
&\leq \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{ \| f(r\cos\theta) \|_{L^2(dr)} \| f(r\sin\theta) \|_{L^2(dr)} }{\cos\theta \vee \sin\theta} \, d\theta \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\| f\|_2^2}{(\cos \theta \vee \sin\theta) \sqrt{\cos\theta\sin\theta}} \, d\theta,
\end{align*}

where $a \vee b := \max \{a, b \}$ is the shorthand notation for the maximum function. Then it is not hard to see that the last integral is bounded.

Comment: You should define your $\vee$ notation. It's not clear what exactly you're doing.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I hope this looks better now.

Comment: Makes sense now!

Comment: Beautiful solution.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer @sos440 . What is $L^2(dr)$?

Comment: @HosseinMoradi, That is the usual $L^2$-norm on $(0,\infty)$, and it also designate the variable w.r.t. which we are integrating.

Comment: @zhw., Thank you! I think you may also like the solution which uses the Minkowski's inequality!

Comment: PS: @sos440 I know you from AOPS. I was WWW there.

Comment: Thank you @sos440 . Do you have any idea about proving non-compactness?

Answer (score 3):

To show noncompactness, let $a> 0$ and set $f_a(x)= (a/2)^{-1/2}\chi_{(a/2,a)}.$ Then $f$ is a unit vector in $L^2.$ It is straightforward to see

$$T(f_a)(x) = \begin{cases} 0,\, 0 < x < a/2 \\
(a/2)^{1/2}/x,\, x> a.\end{cases}.$$

Suppose $a<b/2.$ Because $T(f_b) = 0$ on $(0,b/2),$

$$T(f_a)(x)-T(f_b)(x) = (a/2)^{1/2}/x, a<x<b/2.$$

Thus

$$\int_0^\infty|T(f_a)(x)-T(f_b)(x)|^2\, dx \ge \int_a^{b/2}|T(f_a)(x)|^2\, dx =\frac{1}{2} -\frac{a}{b}.$$

This is $\ge 1/4$ if $a/b\le 1/4.$ It's now easy: The unit vectors $f_{1/4^n}$ satisfy

$$\|T(f_{1/4^n}) - T(f_{1/4^m})\|_2 \ge \frac{1}{2}$$

if $m\ne n.$ Thus no subsequence of $T(f_{1/4^n})$ can be Cauchy. Hence $T$ is not compact.

Comment: This was actually one of my first attempts.  But I ran into problems.  I think I miscalculated $\|Tf_n\|$ with my example, (same as yours).  In hindsight, I think it should've worked though and I just made a mistake somewhere.  Did you get it to work?  Note that it's very similar to my example, but this approach could possibly be slightly simpler.

Comment: I've edited to give a more complete proof.

Comment: neato... plus more characters